# perl assigns key with undefined value

Tags: perl, hashtable

I have a piece of code which used to look like this:

```
$deepest{$xval} = $Evalue unless exists $deepest{$xval}; 

#some code

foreach (keys %deepest){
  print $datfh $_, "\t", $deepest{$_}, "\n";
}
```

Then I changed it to

```
$deepest{$xval} = [$Evalue, $id] unless exists $deepest{$xval}[0];

#some more code

foreach (keys %deepest){
  print $datfh $_, "\t", $deepest{$_}[0], "\t", $deepest{$_}[1], "\n";
}
```

And now I get, when I print the hash afterwards, a lot of warnings:

```
Use of uninitialized value in print
```

which I didn't get before.

Why does the new hash structure work different than the old one? Is there anything I can do to avoid the uninitialized entries?

Update: Stupid me, I didn't include the part of the code that actually caused the error in the original question. Now it's in and now I also know how to get rid of it, namely replacing `exists $deepest{$xval}[0]` by `exists $deepest{$xval}`, somehow the first way creates the hash entry.

Comment: You might want to replace your long `unless` statement with `$deepest{$xval} //= [$Evalue, $id]`. It isn't *exactly* the same, because it will set the value of `$deepest{$xval}` if it exists but has a value of `undef` as well as if it doesn't exist, but that 's almost certainly fine for your purpose

Comment: It seems that you have a key in `%deepest` which its value is an array ref with one element.

Comment: @Borodin thanks for the hint, I will keep that in mind. In this code though, the unless statement contains some more conditions, which I didn't put into the question because they didn't produce the problem, so in this case I have to use the unless anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$deepest{$_}->[0]` (and so on) in the print statement? The values of the hash are array *references*, not arrays.

Comment: the "somehow" has to do with perl's auto-vivification - http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=691557

Comment: @bytepusher thanks for the link

Comment: @HellmarBecker I wondered about this too, but it works for some reason.

Comment: Multiple brackets aren't ambiguous - `$array[0]` might be a scalar or array-ref. However if you specify `$array[0][1]` then you _know_ that `$array[0]` has to be an arrayref, so can safely implicitly dereference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
#should check exists of hash, not array
$deepest{$xval} = [$Evalue, $id] unless exists $deepest{$xval};
# some code
foreach (keys %deepest){
  # its good practice to use -> for arrayrefs and hashrefs ($deepest{$_} - arrayref)
  #and you should check $deepest{$xval}->[1] ( $id ) , maybe $id is undef
  warn '$id is not defined ' unless defined $deepest{$_}->[1];
  print $datfh $_, "\t", $deepest{$_}->[0], "\t", $deepest{$_}->[1],    "\n";
}
```

Comment: This answer could really do with a bit more explanation as to what's going on, and why this resolves it.

Comment: Yes, i have added some comments

Answer (score 1):

Exists tests whether a key exists. That's useful, but it may not be entirely what you want, because it works if the *value* for that key is undef.

You may find `defined` does what you want instead:

```
my %hash = ( key => undef ); 

print "Key exists\n" if exists $hash{$key};
print "Key defined\n" if defined $hash{$key};
```

And in your case:

```
my %hash = ( key => [ ] ); 
print "Exists\n" if exists $hash{key};
print "Defined\n" if defined $hash{key}; 
print "Is true\n" if $hash{key}; 
print "Has values\n" if @{$hash{key}};
```

But looking at your code, my thought would be - that anonymous array you insert - does that definitely always have at least two (defined) elements?

Because one obvious way you could hit that problem is if:

```
my %hash = ( key => [ "value", undef ] ); 
print $hash{key}[0], $hash{key}[1],"\n";
```

Regarding dereferencing (as it's a bit too big for the comments) - you actually only need to dereference once.

Because:

```
my $array_ref = [ 1, 4, 9 ]; 
print $array_ref,"\n"; #scalar value; 
print $array_ref -> [0],"\n"; #also scalar, from within array.
```

If you have however:

```
my @array = ( [1, 4, 9], 
              [16, 25, 36], );
print "@array\n";
print \@array,"\n";
print $array[0],"\n"; #reference scalar - but because of the brackets
                      #perl knows you're referring to @array. 
print $array[0][1],"\n"; #scalar, but implicitly dereferenced.
print $array[0]->[1]; #dereferenced scalar, same as above.
```

The last two cases are the same - why? Well, because it has to be. The 'parent' array *must* be a reference, because that's how an array of arrays works, so `perl` can automagically dereference.